# Count char on file using thread and mutex

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I am working on this problem: take from the command line a letter and the name of same files, count the occurrence of the char in each file, using one thread per file, and and print the total occurrences.

This is my code:

```
typedef struct _CharFile{

    char c;
    char *fileName;

} CharFile;

pthread_mutex_t count = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int sum = 0;

void *CountFile(void *threadarg);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    pthread_t threads[argc-2];
    int chck, t;
    CharFile cf;

    for ( t=0 ; t<argc-2 ; t++ ){

        cf.c = argv[1][0];
        cf.fileName = (char *)argv[t + 2];

        chck = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, CountFile, (void *) &cf);
        if (chck){
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", chck);
            exit(-1);
        }

    }

    printf("%lld occurrences of the letter %c in %lld threads\n", (long long)sum, argv[1][0], (long long)argc-2);

    return 0;
}

void *CountFile(void *threadarg){

    FILE *in;
    CharFile *cf;
    char c;
    int counter = 0;

    cf = (CharFile *) threadarg;
    in = fopen(cf->fileName, "r");

    if (in == NULL){

        perror("Error opening the file!\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);

    }

    while (fscanf(in, "%c", &c) != EOF){

        if(c == cf->c){

            counter += 1;

        }

    }

    fclose(in);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&count);
    sum += counter;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&count);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I don't get any error in the file opening or in the thread creations, but my output is always 0 as total occurrences. I also tried to print the `counter` in the threads and I got every time the same numbers in all the threads, even if my input files are different. Am I using the mutex wrongly or is there something else wrong?

This is one of my outputs:

```
61 occurrences of e in this thread
0 occurrences of the letter e in 3 threads
61 occurrences of e in this thread
61 occurrences of e in this thread
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

Comment: You don't wait for your threads to finish.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: However you want. The way that's usually the worst is to use `pthread_join`. But it's simple and the one you should probably learn first.

Answer (score 0):

There are several threading issues at play here.

1) The main thread will continue asynchronously to the newly spawned threads.  Given the code, it is very likely that the main thread will complete and exit before the CountFile threads have completed.  On Linux, when the main thread returns, the C runtime will perform a exit_group system call which will terminate all threads.

You'll need to add some check to ensure the CountFile threads have finished the relevant section of work.  In this example, look at using pthread_join() in the main thread.

2) The 'cf' storage in the main thread is a stack local variable, which is passed by pointer to each thread.  However, since it is the same storage, several types of failures could occur.  a) the workunit may be updated by the main thread while a worker thread is accessing it.  b) the same workunit is sent to multiple/all threads.

You could solve this several ways: 'cf' could be an array of CharFile for each thread.  Or 'cf' could be dynamically allocated for each thread.  The former is a bit more performance and memory efficient, but the later might be better structurally.  Particularly that main thread is giving addresses in its local stack space to another thread.

3) Once item #1 is addressed and the threads exited before the main thread printf, the mutex usage would be ok.  But it might be better to put pthread_mutex_locks around the main thread access of 'sum' anyway.  It may not be necessary given this code, but future code refactors might change that.